# How to use Magento 2.3 and Cloudfare CDN?

Tags: magento2, magento2.3, static-content, cdn

I'm currently trying out the Cloudflare CDN (free plan), but I didn't notice much in website performance. My server was having "server load" problems and it did stop, but It seems the website's performance isn't much better.

I believe It's because of my Magento's CDN configuration:

So, which URL's should I use for static files and media files? I can't find information about that on Cloudfare's website and I don't know if I'm really retrieving the static files from there or elsewhere. I use Cloudflare's extension for Magento.

[image: Magento 2 and Cloudflare CDN]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to configure a different URL to media and static files; Since Cloudflare manages your domain, it'll deliver the static content using their CDN and get the dynamic content from your server, all of it through your domain.

Reference: https://www.cloudflare.com/learning/cdn/caching-static-and-dynamic-content/